# Force Dash and/or Smart Scopes through Tor Network?

Tags: unity-dash, tor, scopes

When I enter keystrokes into Unity Dash with an original 14.04 setup, my understanding is that these are sent to local- as well as cloud-based "[Smart Scopes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SmartScopes1304Spec)" on Canonical servers.

How can I configure Unity Dash to send my keystrokes through the Tor Network?

I am happy to provide "usage data" to Canonical, but not my IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can put Tor between yourself and Canonical. Tor is activated through a browser. Why not subscribe to a cheap VPN for about $3.00 per month (annual subscription) and hide the IP from everyone? Even Tor would best be used through a VPN.

Comment: The Tor Browser Bundle is a browser that puts Tor between you and the internet. Tor does not require a browser.